# How to create a multiindex inside of a multiindex, is it even possible to do so?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

Currently I have a data frame that looks like

```
 PS        PSX1                   PSX2                   PSX3                   PSX4
      P    TEMP    Pat       P    TEMP    Pat       P    TEMP    Pat       P    TEMP    Pat 
     .01   77     IDLE      .04   77     IDLE      .003  77     IDLE      .19   77      IDLE
     .03   77     WRITE     .1    77     WRITE     .011  77     WRITE     .28   77      WRITE
     .02   77     READ      .04   77     READ      .004  77     READ      .25   77      READ
     .03   77     WRITE     .04   77     WRITE     .010  77     WRITE     .39   77      WRITE
     .02   77     READ      .04   77     READ      .195  77     READ      .24   77      READ
     .01   230    IDLE      .04   230    IDLE      .003  230    IDLE      .19   230     IDLE
     .02   230    WRITE     .1    230    WRITE     .019  230    WRITE     .29   230     WRITE
     .     .       .        .     .       .          .    .       .         .    .        .
     .     .       .        .     .       .          .    .       .         .    .        .
     .     .       .        .     .       .          .    .       .         .    .        .
     .     .       .        .     .       .          .    .       .         .    .        .
```

Eventually in the dataframe the temperature changes to 302.

I wanted to know if there was a way to change the above dataframe to look like the one below (it should still include PSX3 and PSX4 I just slimmed it down so it's easier to look at)

```
PS             PSX1                PSX2               
TEMP     77    230   302     77    230   302    
         P      P     P      P      P     P
IDLE    .01    .01   .01    .04    .04   .04 
WRITE   .03    .02   .04    .1     .1    .2
READ    .02    .03   .03    .04    .1    .1  
WRITE   .03    .02   .02    .09    .1    .1
READ    .02    .02   .02    .1     .1    .1
```

I made the first grouping using these 2 lines of code

```
 df1 = df1.assign(newIndex = df1.groupby('PS').cumcount())
 df1 = df1.set_index(['newIndex', 'PS']).unstack().swaplevel(0, axis = 1).sort_index(axis = 1, level = 0)
```

I tried doing this again but at level 1 and I can't seem to get it to work. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not very clear on desired results.  Can you limit it two just three complete column records and show what your expected output would be with those three complete columns?

Comment: @ScottBoston I edited the output table, is that more useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
(df.stack(0)
  .set_index(['Pat','TEMP'],append=True)
  .unstack([-1,1])
  .swaplevel(0,2, axis=1)
  .sum(level=1).sort_index(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
       PSX1        PSX2         PSX3         PSX4      
TEMP    77    230   77    230    77     230   77    230
          P     P     P     P      P      P     P     P
Pat                                                    
IDLE   0.01  0.01  0.04  0.04  0.003  0.003  0.19  0.19
WRITE  0.06  0.02  0.14  0.10  0.021  0.019  0.67  0.00
READ   0.04  0.00  0.08  0.00  0.199  0.000  0.49  0.00
WRIT   0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.000  0.000  0.00  0.29
```